# PHP PEAR HTTP_Request: uses SSL when not desired

Tags: php, pear

I have a script that is using the PEAR HTTP_Request library to retrieve data from the site via a URL:

```
$url = 'http://myurl.com';
$request = new HTTP_Request($url);
$request->sendRequest();
$response = $request->getResponseBody();
```

Despite the URL being passed as non-ssl, it is being retrieved over SSL (which results in a 302 error in the response body, as the site does not use SSL).

If I log the initial $request object, everything looks fine -- the URL is structured correctly, protocol is http, port is 80. If I log $request after ->sendRequest(), $request->_url is configured correctly, but $request->_response->_headers shows the URL as https.

Why would it convert it? How can I force it to retrieve the page over HTTP?

Comment: Because 302 is a redirect? You ask for http, server replies with a redirect to https.

Comment: I know 302 is a redirect. But we're not (intentionally) redirecting the URL anywhere. It's getting redirected to SSL when it shouldn't. The URL can be accessed correctly from the browser -- but when retrieved via the HTTP_Request class the redirect is happening.

Comment: Do you control the server? Because the server is sending the header telling your client to redirect. Also, the server may react differently when connecting from a browser, vs. a curl library call like `HTTP_Request`, so you can't necessarily draw a conclusion of global behavior from a browser's behavior. Have you tried your URL from the command line, with `curl`? That will show you a more similar operation.